# Best practice column structure

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I was just wondering witch one of these 2 options is prefered when i want to soft delete?

> **Option 1:** Creating 2 columns in my table, one named *'IsDeleted'* and the other *'DeletedAt'*.
>
> When i do it like this, i first need to check if an item is deleted. 
>   Then if i need to know when it was deleted i can check that to.
>
> **Option 2:** Just use *'DeletedAt'* and check if its null in my code.

Please motivate your answere.

Comment: The former, along with the user id of the person that deleted it.  *You can do it, answer!*

Comment: I prefer not to work at all with "null" values. Too much thing make happen with it. Option 1 is a normal way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer Option 1 over the second one.
What makes me feel like this is the better thing to do is that you keep the possibility to manipulate the status of your deletion without losing data.
Also, every column would then have an explicit meaning without creating dependencies (deciding whether or not something is deleted AND when) which might obstruct you at a later point.

Option 2 would make a column serve a purpose it was (maybe) not designed for which feels kind of "dirty" to me.